# compare two UIButton.tag elements in one array objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have an array called '_orderOfCardPlacement' which gets objects put in it after every turn of my game. These objects are UIButtons which have a number of details such as setImage, setBounds, setCenter and most importantly to this question setTag. There are two possible outcomes for setTag either '1' or '2', They are initially set with one or the other and this can be changed via another method which is called every turn. What i need to do is look through this array and see how many times '1' has come up and how many times '2' has come up and then compare that result. So if '1' comes up nine times and '2' comes up 7 times then '1' wins in this case. So when i NSLog my array (say after one turn) i get this:

```
"<OBShapedButton: 0x7ff6f968e6a0; baseClass = UIButton; frame = (103 387.5; 150 135); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ff6f968e8a0>>"
```

and subsequent turns will add more buttons to the array. But I need to know once this array is full and the game is complete how to access the 'tag = ' part of the objects to compare. Thanks for any advice, ill add more code if necessary!

Here's the solution in full, if there's a more elegant way to do what i'm doing here, definitely interested to know!

```
//set the amount of cards each player has
_howManyCardsForComputer = 0;
_howManyCardsForPlayer = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < _orderOfCardPlacement.count; i++) {
    UIButton *auxButton = (UIButton *) [_orderOfCardPlacement objectAtIndex:i];
    NSInteger playerScore = auxButton.tag;
    NSMutableArray *totalScoreArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [totalScoreArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:playerScore]];
    for (int j = 0; j < totalScoreArray.count; j++) {
        if ([[totalScoreArray objectAtIndex:j] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1]]) {
            _howManyCardsForPlayer++;
        }
        if ([[totalScoreArray objectAtIndex:j] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:2]]) {
            _howManyCardsForComputer++;
        }
    }
}

_playerScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Players cards %i", _howManyCardsForPlayer];
_playerScore.hidden = NO;
_computerScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Computers cards %i", _howManyCardsForComputer];
_computerScore.hidden = NO;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood clearly what you want to achieve. If your buttons are stored in a NSMutableArray, you can check their tags by geting the i-th element (inside a for-loop) and apply a casting.

```
NSMutableArray *arrayWithButtons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//... Fill the array

//Check tags
for(int i=0; i<numButtons; i++){
    UIButton *auxButton = (UIButton*) [arrayWithButton objectAtIndex:i];
    int auxTag = auxButton.tag;
    //... perform the proper operations
}
```

I hope I understand it well, and this can help you.

Comment: Thank you! This is great as it correctly shows the changes to the tags over time via nslog, however i need to add up all the times '1' comes up and all the times '2' comes up. I feel like i'm gonna kick myself when i figure it out but for now i'm stuck on that bit.